# How to stretch my listview to scrollview's heigth?

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

How to stretch the listView in this given code to match his grandparents frame(parent = linearlayout, grandparent = scrollview). so far, my listview stretches upto 3 items only. :(

here's the code:

```
        <ScrollView android:layout_span="2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="90pt">
            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_span="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView android:id="@android:id/empty" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:typeface="monospace" android:layout_height="0dip" android:text="@string/immu_no_list_data_text" android:layout_weight="1.0" android:textSize="20dp"></TextView>
                <ListView android:layout_weight="1.0" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/list_immu" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ListView>

            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any particular reason why you need a scrollview?

ListView and ScrollView don't play well together. The list view will handle scrolling itself. Try:

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
   <TextView ... />
   <ListView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just to corner my buttons at the bottom of the screen! yeah! hehe
Any other idea to frame my linear Layout? hehe.

Because my real problem is that, when the list is populated dynamically, it pushes my buttons way down the screen it the user cannot view or use it.:(

Comment: You should add the complete layout and/or a screenshot to explain what you need to acheive.